# Prove that the function $ \zeta(x)=\sum^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{x}}, x>1 $ is infinitely differentiable in $(1, \infty) . n=1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, derivatives, power-series

Prove that if $a>1$ and $k \geq 1,$ then

- a)  $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(\log n)^{k}}{n^{a}}<\infty$
- b)  Prove that the function
  $$
  \zeta(x)=\sum^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{x}}, x>1
  $$
  is infinitely differentiable in $(1, \infty) . n=1$
  Hint: Use part (a) to prove part (b). You can use part (a) to prove (b), even if you do not know how to prove (a).

**My try:**

- a)  As $\frac{(\log n)^{k}}{n^{a}}$ in monotonically decreasing because $\ln n$ grows slowly than $n^{a}$. **Is there a rigorous way to prove it?** I tried in this way that
  $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{(\log x)^{k}}{x^{a}}\right)=\frac{\frac{k}{x}(\log x)^{k-1}-a x^{a-1}}{x^{2 a}}=\frac{k(\log x)^{k-1}-a x^{a}}{x^{2 a+1}}$
  and in this way inductively I was trying to see that $f(x)<f(y)$ whenn $x>y$ for some large $y$. *But not convinced fully.*

Thus we can use Cauchy's Condensation test, considering $f(n)=\frac{(\log n)^{k}}{n^{a}}$.

$\begin{aligned} 2^{n} f\left(2^{n}\right)=& \frac{2^{n}\left(\log 2^{n}\right)^{k}}{\left(2^{n}\right)^{a}}=\frac{\sin n^{k}(\log 2)^{k}}{2^{n(a-1)}} \\ &=\frac{n^{k} c}{2^{d n}} ; \text { where }\left(\log {2}\right)^{k}=c \text { finite constant }, d=a-1>0 \text { finite constant .}\end{aligned}$

Now, $\sum f(n)$ converges iff $\sum 2^{n} f\left(2^{n}\right)$ converges
iff $\sum \frac{n^{k}}{2^{d n}}$ converges.
By Ratio test the last series converges and hence the result.

- For part b) I can see that $h(x)=\frac{1}{n^{x}}=n^{-x}$ then $h'(x)=-n^{-x}\log n$ and $h''(x)=n^{-x}(\log n)^2$ and so on. Then I can see that the series with term by term differentiation of $\zeta(x)$ is convergent. **How to conclude my answer from there?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part (a):** You can use the fact that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\log x)^k}{x^{(a-1)/2}} = 0$$ to show that $$\frac{(\log x)^k}{x^a} \leq \frac{1}{x^{(a+1)/2}},$$

and so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\log n)^k}{n^a}$ converges by [direct comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{(a+1)/2}}$, which is a [$p$-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series) with $p = (a+1)/2 > 1$, hence convergent.

**Part (b):** Let $f_n(x) = n^{-x}$, then $\zeta(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ is a function series, so if the series $\sum_{n\geq 1} f_n(x)$ [converges uniformly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability) to $\zeta(x)$ on $[a, \infty)$ for any fixed $a > 1$, then it's legitimate to [term-by-term differentiate it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability) to get the derivative of the infinite sum. Since $a > 1$ is arbitrary here, that means $\zeta$ is infinitely differentiable on all of $(1, \infty)$ and its derivatives are gotten by term-by-term differentiation.

Comment: Is there any way to prove the term of the series is decreasing to use Cauchy condensation in part a)?

Comment: @Ri-Li If you're hell-bent on using Cauchy condensation, in your original post you proved that the terms are *eventually* monotone decreasing, which is good enough.

Comment: No, I haven't proved the monotone decreasing part. I stated the log and exponentiation part. How to prove that rigorously that the terms are monotonically decreasing? I went on proving but I couldn't.

One more observation, in the question they asked me to use part a to prove part b). Where have you used part a) in your argument?

Comment: @Ri-Li To show monotone decrease, just show that the first derivative is negative for sufficiently large $x$. Part (a) is implicitly used in part (b) because if you want to say the derivative of $\zeta$ is equal to the $\zeta$-series differentiated term-by-term, you'd better know that the term-by-term differentiated series converges too.

Comment: Yeah, I was also assuming so in the second part and thanks for confirming. By the way, for part a) why is the first derivative negative? I was stuck at the expression $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{(\log x)^{k}}{x^{a}}\right)=\frac{\frac{k}{x}(\log x)^{k-1}-a x^{a-1}}{x^{2 a}}=\frac{k(\log x)^{k-1}-a x^{a}}{x^{2 a+1}}$.

Comment: @Ri-Li Look at the numerator of that fraction. Since you know the overall fraction is tending to $0$, that also implies that $k(log x)^{k-1} << ax^a$ for $x$ sufficiently large, so the numerator is negative when $x$ gets big enough.